# jQuery show/hide rendering duplicate content

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm pretty new to jquery so bear with me. I'm doing a simple show/hide on multiple div's. Basically you hover over an image with a class and are shown the content from a div with the corresponding class. The thing I'm running into is if you hover over an image and then hover over another image there are instances when I'm seeing content from the previous hover and the current one essentially duplicating content. This is really only when your hovering fast over images but annoying none the less. Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

  jQuery('.company').not(':first').hide();

  jQuery('#company_container img').on('hover', function(){

var contenttoShow = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');

    contenttoShow2 = jQuery(contenttoShow);
    jQuery('.company').hide();
    contenttoShow2.fadeIn(500);
  });

});

<div class="company" id="company_1">
<p>some content goes here</p>
</div>

<div class="company" id="company_2">
<p>some content goes here</p>
</div>

<div class="company" id="company_3">
<p>some content goes here</p>
</div>

<div id="company_container">
 <a title="" href="#"><img data-title="#company_1" src="test.jpg" /></a>
 <a title="" href="#"><img data-title="#company_2" src="test2.jpg" /></a>
 <a title="" href="#"><img data-title="#company_3" src="test3.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you...

```
jQuery('.company').not(':first').hide();

jQuery('#company_container img').mouseover(function() {
   jQuery('.company').hide();
   var contenttoShow = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
   jQuery(contenttoShow).fadeIn(500);      

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ba6SZ/

Comment: Thanks @Loren except I'm really confused on why this would work better. Any ideas, and thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.hover()` instead

```
jQuery('#company_container img').hover(function () {
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/VereA/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .on() is to `Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Often used to attach events to dynamically created elements.

Watch out for multiple event binding. In this small demo every time the box is clicked it is evoked in 2^x increasing times. (x being the click count). This had me scratching my head a while back.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/acNwn/